# Access items from system_profiler plist

Tags: objective-c, macos, plist

I have a plist file generated by `system_profiler -xml` command: [image: plist file]

How can I get to that `cpu_type` or `machine_name` and store them in `NSString`s?

I tried many methods, even converting this file into JSON, but couldn't get to those elements.

Example:

[image: Code]

`str` is `nil`

The path seems to be something like:

`root \ 0 \ _items \ 0 \ cpu_type
 root \ 0 \ _items \ 0 \ current_processor_speed
 ...`

There is no enumeration here, so I should be able to get straight to those keys, but I don't know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[arr valueForKey:@"cpu_type"]` will not work because `arr` is an array, not a dictionary. To access the value you want, try this

```
NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath][0];
NSDictionary *itemsDictionary = rootDictionary[@"_items"][0];
NSString *CPUType = itemsDictionary[@"cpu_type"];
```

Note that `[0]` is shorthand for `[array objectAtIndex:0]`, and `[@"key"]` is short for `[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"]`

Getting `machine_name` would be done in the same fashion

```
NSString *machineName = itemsDictionary[@"machine_name"];
```